# What distributions support "armel" (not armhf)?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, debian, arm, linux-distributions

[Debian Stretch is EOL](https://wiki.debian.org/LTS/), which was the last to support the `armel` architecture (arm ~v5 soft float).  Everything seems to have gone to `armhf` (hardware float) or `aarch64`.

Are there any modern distributions as a viable replacement for Debian that support `armel` out of the box?

(This is for [Lego ev3dev](https://www.ev3dev.org/) since the Lego EV3 runs `armel`).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not closely familiar with Linux distributions and features/options you need. But **Devuan GNU+Linux** (a fork of Debian without systemd, lastest version Chimaera 4.0 is based on Debian Bullseye 11.1) seems to be available for ***armel*** architecture.

Download and see details on their site: https://www.devuan.org/